# Python won't write \r\n to XML file

Tags: python, python-3.x, xml, newline, xml.etree

I am using python to generate XML files. The XML files have attributes that require `\r\n` to denote a line break (regular `\n` will not work for this application). Here's an example of the XML file I am trying to generate:

```
<root>
    <tag attrib="multiple&#13;&#10;lines&#13;&#10;here"></tag>
</root>
```

Note the `&#10;` is the XML escape character encoding for `\n` and `&#13;` is `\r`.

Here is my python code to generate this XML file:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET


root = ET.Element('root')
tag = ET.SubElement(root, 'tag')
tag.set('attrib', 'multiple\r\nlines\r\nhere')

xml_file = 'test.xml'
tree = ET.ElementTree(root)
tree.write(xml_file)
```

Output: `<root><tag attrib="multiple&#10;lines&#10;here" /></root>`

**It is clear that the `\r` is stripped from the output XML. How can I add `\r\n` to my XML files?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a few hours of searching for this, I eventually found that it is a bug in the XML package (See https://bugs.python.org/issue39011). From what I can tell on the cpython github page, this is fixed on Python 3.9, but not any earlier versions. For versions without the bug fix, here is a workaround I've used:

```
with open(xml_file, 'r') as f:
    lines = f.read()

with open(xml_file, 'w') as f:
    lines = f.write(lines.replace('&#10;', '&#13;&#10;')
```

After you create an XML file without `\r\n`, you open it and replace any occurrences of `\n` in the attributes with `\r\n`.